# Не работают виртуальные хосты apache2. Apache возвращает стартовую страницу?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, unix

Извините если тема повторяется, ничего не нагуглил. После установки обновлений перестали работать виртуальные хосты. Просто каждый хост возвращает стартовую страницу apache. А если добавить параметры, например my-host.local/index - тогда работу перехвачивает nginx (хотя я вовсе не помню чтобы его устанавливал).

Результат `sudo apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost grav.loc (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/grav.loc.conf:1)
                 alias www.grav.loc
         port 80 namevhost local.node.js (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/local.node.js.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost lottery.loc (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/lottery.loc.conf:1)
                 alias www.lottery.loc
         port 80 namevhost mirage.loc (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mirage.loc.conf:1)
                 alias www.mirage.loc
         port 80 namevhost prototype.loc (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prototype.loc.conf:1)
                 alias www.prototype.loc
         port 80 namevhost revol.loc (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/revol.loc.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost work.loc (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/work.loc.conf:1)
                 alias www.work.loc
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Comment: а в какие ip-адреса резолвятся все эти имена?

Comment: Все работает локально. В конфиге не указано ip, а просто *:80, пробовал менять на 127.0.1.1:80 не помогает